# Is it possible to achieve this in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a text in a width-limited div element (Bootstrap container). Below it, I want to have a scrolling view with some tiles. I want the scrolling view to have full page width, but its content to be aligned with the above text. Initially, it looks like below, all good:

[image]

However, when scrolled to the end, the content should be aligned to the right edge of the text element as well, which is not happening:

[image]

```css
  

  .container {
      max-width:400px;
      margin:auto;
    }

    .tile {
      display:inline-block;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      margin-right:10px;
      background-color:yellow;
    }

    .tile:last-child {
      margin-right:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h3 style="background-color:red;">Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div style="width:auto;white-space:nowrap;overflow-y:hidden;">
      <div style="overflow-x:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
          <div class="tile"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, add the same amount of margin that the `h3` element has to the first and last tile?

Comment: @SourceOverflow `h3` doesn't have any margin itself, its `.container` has automatic margins because of its `max-width`, so I can't just add the same margin, that's the problem.

Comment: So basically, you want the last yellow block once scrolled all the way to the left, to align it's right edge with the right edge of the red background of the title?

Comment: what about adding `overflow-x: scroll` to your `.container`?

Comment: @disinfor yes. I can do that with one line of Javascript to update right margin of the last tile on window size change, but the question is if it's possible without JS.

Comment: must your `.tile` width be 100px? If not you can switch to percentage instead and let the title width according to its parent

Comment: I tried every possible html/css method, not working. Might need Js/Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rap2j7e/) will help.

I've added right margin to the last tile to compensate container gap. It is calculated this way: `margin-right:calc((100vw - 400px )/2)`. Half of the difference between window width and container width (`400px`).

```
.tile:last-child {
    margin-right:calc((100vw - 400px )/2);
}
```

I have added additional CSS like following to nullify the margin of the body tag. Otherwise `100vh` will include additional `8px`.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the tiles in the container like i have done below. you tiles are flowing out of the container that is why is not aligning properly.

```
  .container {
      max-width:400px;
      margin:auto;
    }

    .tile {
      display:inline-block;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      margin-right:10px;
      background-color:yellow;
    }

    .tile:last-child {
      margin-right:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
          <h3 style="background-color:red;">Title</h3>
        </div>
<div class="container">
        <div style="width:auto;white-space:nowrap;overflow-y:hidden;">
          <div style="overflow-x:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">

              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
              <div class="tile"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container h3{
  margin:1rem 2rem;
}
.tile {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-right:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.tile:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 style="background-color:red;">Title</h3>
</div>
<div style="width:auto;white-space:nowrap;overflow-y:hidden;">
  <div style="overflow-x:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've added right margin to the last tile to compensate container gap. It is calculated this another way: margin-right:calc((400px -100vw)/2). I used subtraction operator to find the margin-right.
 Half of the difference between window width and container width (400px).